# Rails API Mode JBuilder Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, pagination, kaminari, jbuilder

I am currently trying to work on a large data set with over 9000 records coming in and would like to paginate it. I have never worked with pagination I know the gems Kaminari and Pagy can do this. I believe I need to wrap my find with either Kaminari supplied methods or Pagy but I am not sure what I am supposed to do with my Jbuilder views after that. Below is a snippet of my find method and a builder for it. The attendees hash has roughly 9000 records causing the load to either time out or take about 5 minutes. I am hoping pagination should smooth this out.

```rb
Controller
  class ConferencesController < ::ApplicationController
    def attendees
      @conference = Conference.find(attendee_params[:conference_id])
    end

    private

    def attendee_params
      params.permit(:conference_id)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
View
json.full_name attendee.full_name
json.email attendee.email
json.requires_certification attendee.requires_certification
```

Output

```
{
  "conference": {
    "title": "Avengers Assemble",
    "description": null,
    "starts_at": "2021-04-21T16:00:00.0000+0000",
    "ends_at": "2021-04-21T16:45:00.0000+0000",
    "attendees_count": 9002
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "full_name": "Steve Rogers",
      "email": "blank@blank.com",
      "requires_certification": true
    },
    {
      "full_name": "Bruce Banner",
      "email": "denise.parisian@kirlin.biz",
      "requires_certification": false
    },
    {
      "full_name": "THor Odinson",
      "email": "blank@blank.com",
      "requires_certification": false
    }
```